# I can't create a big box that is grey on my website with bootstrap's "well" command

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code on codepens html sheet :

```
<body>
  <div class="well">
      <h1 class="text-primary container-fluid well"> My school - "HTL Donaustadt" </h1>
  </div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2207244694/Logo_CMYK_300dpi_400x400.jpg"
</body>
```

you can see I inserted the word "well" from bootstrap two times , both didn't worked . First i tried it out with the divison to do a parent ( didn't worked ) also i used it as a class in the h1 ( also didn't worked ) . My goal is just to do a center grey box where i can put images and text in . I'm a newbie so sorry for those bad and easy questions. Also , just to understand - is "container" something that i need to understand here to complete this easy task ?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Im pretty sure they removed the well in v4.

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap css on your site?  I don't know what you expect but the code definitly works: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/g695tLyn/)

Comment: you say , i have to do the linking at the top of the page like usual , even on code pen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Hope this is what you need. In the code provided by you there is no closing brace ">" for image. The problem you might have faced is because you might not have included the source file for bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="well">
          <h1 class="text-primary container-fluid well"> My school - "HTL Donaustadt" </h1>
      </div>
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2207244694/Logo_CMYK_300dpi_400x400.jpg">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jeah the code is right , also i forgot to add the bootstrap library link at the top of the html document , i thought in codepen you dont need to do that after setting bootstrap version 4 in the options even .... sorry for the mistakes